# Tfs Build Server 2015 publish specific project

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I want to use the TFS Build server. I want the build server to build related projects, publish and deploy to other servers.

I have set up the server and build agent. It is time to define build definitions. But I have a problem here.

We use VS 2015 and we have a big solution. It includes many dll projects, web sites and a WCF project.

I want to define build definitions for each web sites seperatly. 
for example when I run build definition A, it should only publish website A.
And I do not want to build the whole solution to publish website A. Only necessary projects should be built.

How can I do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using vNext build or Xaml based build?

Comment: ok instead of specifying the .sln file try to specify the csproj file, but you will need to change a lot in the Msbuild command.

Comment: can you give example or source ?

Comment: Give me some time. I might be wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have finally found a solution.

- Firstly, i added VisualStudioBuild Task,
- set Solution Path variable
  to the .csproj file that i wanted to build and publish,
- set Repository and cloak unnecessary projects,
- set MSBuild Arguments as;

  ```
  /p:OutputPath=bin/$(BuildConfiguration)
  /p:DeployOnBuild=True
  /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
  /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd
  /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true 
  /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/xxx" 
  /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 
  /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 
  /p:UserName=xxx
  /p:password=xxx
  ```

The important argument is OutPutPath here. If you do not give this property and try to build a csproj,  msbuild throws exception.